# Thevenin's resistance with a dependant source

Tags: resistance, thevenin

I have this circuit for which we must find the Thevenin resistance in considering the load is \$R_L\$. For this case I calculated \$E_{th}=-\beta i_b R_4\$ by shorting the load resistor \$R_L\$ so the short circuit current is equal to \$-\beta i_b\$ so the Thevenin resistance is \$R_4\$. And if I use the method where I remove the load \$R_L\$ and I replace it by a current generator of \$1 A\$ the Thevenin resistance would be \$(1+\beta i_b) R_4\$. Where is the mistake I made?
[image]

Comment: I'm confused by what's presented (though it looks something like the small-signal (1st order differential) hybrid-\$\pi\$ model with RL as the collector resistor) together with your writing. I may be the only one confused and it is entirely my problem and none of yours. But perhaps others are unsure, as well, about your work product and where to help. If so, you may need to write more.

Answer (score 0):

The effective thevenin source resistance is given by change in voltage / change in current. So if you short circuit the output the voltage changes from the unloaded value to zero and current goes from zero to the short circuit current. So the resistance is the unloaded voltage / short circuit current, which is equal to R4 as you stated. In you circuit, if you replace the load with a zero amp current source, the output voltage would be βib * R4. With a 1A source the voltage is (1+βib)R4, as you stated. The difference in voltage is
(1+βib)R4 - βib * R4 = R4 + βib*R4 - βib*R4 = R4
The mistake was not subtracting the output voltage at zero current.

Comment: can you say why you substrat that voltage ?

Comment: @MouhKramo The output resistance of a circuit is not simply the voltage you see then applying 1A. Imagine a simple circuit of -1A source and 1k resistor. If we apply a +1A source we get 0V at the output, but its resistance is not 0ohms but 1kohm. It is the ratio of change in voltage to change in current dV/di if you like. So we can get resistance in ohms by the difference in terminal voltage between 0A applied and 1A applied, the difference being (V at 1A) - (V at 0A)

Answer (score -1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying the analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKfChw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_3+\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_3\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6+\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_4+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_1
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}+\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I4 == I3 + n*I3, 0 == I5 + I6 + n*I3, 
   I7 == I5 + I6, 0 == I0 + I4 + I7, I2 == I0 + I1, 
   I1 == (V0 - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I4 == V2/R4, 
   I5 == V3/R5, I6 == V3/R6}, {V0, V1, V2, V3, I0, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6,
    I7}]]

Out[1]={{V0 -> I1 (R1 + R2 - R2^2/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4)), 
  V1 -> (I1 R2 (R3 + R4 + n R4))/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4), 
  V2 -> (I1 (1 + n) R2 R4)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4), 
  V3 -> -((I1 n R2 R5 R6)/((R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4) (R5 + R6))), 
  I0 -> -((I1 R2)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4)), 
  I2 -> I1 - (I1 R2)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4), 
  I3 -> (I1 R2)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4), 
  I4 -> (I1 (1 + n) R2)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4), 
  I5 -> -((I1 n R2 R6)/((R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4) (R5 + R6))), 
  I6 -> -((I1 n R2 R5)/((R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4) (R5 + R6))), 
  I7 -> -((I1 n R2)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4))}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_3\$ and letting \$\text{R}_6\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=-\frac{\text{n}\text{I}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\left(1+\text{n}\right)}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_6\$ and letting \$\text{R}_6\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=-\frac{\text{n}\text{I}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\left(1+\text{n}\right)}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\text{R}_5\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[-((I1 n R2 R5 R6)/((R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4) (R5 + R6))), 
  R6 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=-((I1 n R2 R5)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4))

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[-((I1 n R2 R5)/((R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4) (R5 + R6))), R6 -> 0]]

Out[3]=-((I1 n R2)/(R2 + R3 + R4 + n R4))

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=R5
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote on my answer? This way I can learn from the 'mistake' I made and improve my skillset. Thanks a lot.